# Better ImageView rotation rather than doing Bitmap in Android?

Tags: android, performance, bitmapimage

I have a problem with using bitmap when I am going to rotate my ImageView like a compass. Although with Bitmap, it rotates perfectly.

However, after looking deeper into the memory monitor and the logcat, I get a huge dump of traces saying:

```
    01-21 21:05:56.556  22147-22147/.../
dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 11983K, 21% free 56247K/70808K, 
paused 15ms, total 15ms
```

For me, that is not a good sign and that happens when I am using Bitmap, anyone who could give me advice on avoiding GC havoc? The code below is called inside a Sensor method "onSensorChanged()" (Code below, mFragment is a WeakReference while mBitmapOrg is a bitmap). I would rather not go using Android NDK if that is the optimal choice.

```
    private void rotateImageView(ImageView imageView, int drawable, float rotate) {


    DisplayMetrics mDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    mFragment.get().getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().
            getMetrics(mDisplayMetrics);
    int width = mBitmapOrg.getWidth(), height = mBitmapOrg.getHeight();
    Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
    rotate = rotate % 360;
    mMatrix.postRotate( rotate, width, height );
    Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mBitmapOrg, 0, 0, width, height, mMatrix, true);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(mFragment.get().getResources(), rotatedBitmap);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
    imageView.setScaleType( ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER );
}
```

Below is onSensorChanged:

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    if (mFromLocation == null || mToLocation == null ||
            mArrowCompass == null || event == null) return;
    switch (event.sensor.getType())

    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesAccelerometer, 0, 3);
            break;
        case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
            System.arraycopy(event.values, 0, mValuesMagneticField, 0, 3);
            break;
    }

    boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(mMatrixR, mMatrixI,
            mValuesAccelerometer,
            mValuesMagneticField);

    // calculate a new smoothed azimuth value and store to mAzimuth
    if (success)

    {
        SensorManager.getOrientation(mMatrixR, mMatrixValues);
        mAzimuth = (float) Math.toDegrees(mMatrixValues[0]);
        mAzimuth -= getGeomagneticField(mFromLocation).getDeclination(); // converts magnetic north into true north
        mBearTo = mFromLocation.bearingTo(mToLocation);

        // If the bearTo is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
        if (mBearTo < 0) {
            mBearTo = mBearTo + 360;
        }

        //This is where we choose to point it
        mDirectionToDest = (mBearTo - mAzimuth) % 360;

        // If the direction is smaller than 0, add 360 to get the rotation clockwise.
        if (mDirectionToDest < 0) {
            mDirectionToDest = mDirectionToDest + 360;
        }
        final float mDirection = mDirectionToDest;
        rotateImageView(mArrowCompass.get(), R.drawable.compass_arrow, mDirection);
    }
}
```

Comment: try to rotate view instead bitmap

Comment: rotate the ImageView's internal Matrix, get it by calling imageView.getImageMatrix() and use scaleType = "matrix"

Comment: tried, didn't work, could you show me an example for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to rotate ImageView instead of Bitmap.createBitmap() in your rotateImageView() function.

(from gio's and pskink's comment above.)

```java
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);

Matrix mMatrix = new Matrix();
imageView.setImageMatrix(mMatrix);
mMatrix = imageView.getImageMatrix();
mMatrix.postRotate(rotate, width, height);
```